# Consuming extended properties using aspnet identity and WEB FORMS (VS2013.3)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

am currently teaching myself ASP.net using VS 2013.3 and implementing aspnet identity(code first) using Webforms.

I have followed a few MVC tutorials to see if I can learn that way but not having much success.

I would like to add additional properties like Name and Age to the user profile.

**So I create a class Application user which inherits from IdentityUser,**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String Age{ get; set; }
}
```

**I then changed my database context to use this new user**

```
public ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
 ...
}
```

**So far so good - I can register new users with code straight out of the box**

```
public partial class Register : Page
{
    EPMSContext db = new EPMSContext();

    protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = Email.Text, Email = Email.Text, Name = Name.Text, Age=Age.Text,  };
        IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, isPersistent: false);

            IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
        }
        else 
        {
            ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

**I am struggling to implement how I then consume this new profile information in other pages?**

Can someone point me to some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Id of the user logged in can be got from User.Identity.GetUserId(). On any page you can use this with the UserManager to get the user object

```
          var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

You can then access the user profile

```
          user.FirstName; user.Age;
```

Hope this answers your question